# Failed to send email: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined in emailjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, email, mern

I am using Emailjs for sending mail from my frontend contact form. But I am getting a error which is:

Error:
Failed to send email: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
at D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\api\sendPost.js:8:21
at new Promise ()
at Object.sendPost (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\api\sendPost.js:7:12)
at Object.send (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\emailjs-com\cjs\methods\send\send.js:25:23)
at emailController (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\controllers\UserControllers.js:77:36)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\Visual Studio Code\Projects\MERN Projects\Portfolio\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15

Contact.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import {
  FaEnvelopeOpen,
  FaPhoneSquareAlt,
  FaFacebookF,
  FaInstagram,
  FaLinkedin,
  FaGithub,
} from "react-icons/fa";
import { FiSend } from "react-icons/fi";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Loader from "../../components/Loader/Loader";
import "./Contact.css";
import axios from "axios";

const phoneNumber = "+8801704672028";

const handlePhoneClick = () => {
  window.location.href = `tel:${phoneNumber}`;
};

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
  });

  const handleEmailClick = () => {
    window.location.href = `mailto:hasan.mahadi2903@gmail.com`;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check if all form fields are filled
    if (
      formData.name.trim() === "" ||
      formData.email.trim() === "" ||
      formData.subject.trim() === "" ||
      formData.message.trim() === ""
    ) {
      toast.error("Please fill all the fields");
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);

    try {
      // Send the form data to your backend API
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/send", formData);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        toast.success("Message sent successfully");
      } else {
        throw new Error("Failed to send message");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Failed to send message");
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <section className="contact section">
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <h2 className="section_title">
            Get In <span>Touch</span>
          </h2>

          <div className="contact_container container grid">
            <div className="contact_data">
              <h3 className="contact_title">Don't be Shy!</h3>
              <p className="contact_description">
                Feel free to get in touch with me. I am always open to
                discussing new projects, creative ideas, or opportunities to be
                part of your visions
              </p>

              <div className="contact_info">
                <div className="info_item">
                  <FaEnvelopeOpen
                    className="info_icon"
                    onClick={handleEmailClick}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                  <div>
                    <span className="info_title">Mail me</span>
                    <h4 className="info_desc">hasan.mahadi2903@gmail.com</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="info_item">
                  <FaPhoneSquareAlt
                    className="info_icon"
                    onClick={handlePhoneClick}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                  <div>
                    <span className="info_title">Call me</span>
                    <h4 className="info_desc">{phoneNumber}</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="contact_socials">
                <a
                  href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100064028100652&mibextid=ZbWKwL"
                  className="contact_social-link"
                >
                  <FaFacebookF />
                </a>
                <a
                  href="https://instagram.com/mahadi_hasan2903?igshid=NGExMmI2YTkyZg=="
                  className="contact_social-link"
                >
                  <FaInstagram />
                </a>
                <a
                  href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/md-mahadi-hasan-425660258"
                  className="contact_social-link"
                >
                  <FaLinkedin />
                </a>
                <a
                  href="https://github.com/MahadiHasan2903"
                  className="contact_social-link"
                >
                  <FaGithub />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <form className="contact_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form_input-group">
                <div className="form_input-div">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    placeholder="Your Name"
                    className="form_control"
                    value={formData.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form_input-div">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="Your Email"
                    className="form_control"
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form_input-div">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="subject"
                    placeholder="Your Subject"
                    className="form_control"
                    value={formData.subject}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form_input-div">
                <textarea
                  name="message"
                  placeholder="Your Message"
                  className="form_control"
                  value={formData.message}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                ></textarea>
              </div>

              <button className="button" type="submit">
                Send Message
                <span className="button_icon contact_button_icon">
                  <FiSend />
                </span>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

controller:

```
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const emailjs = require("emailjs-com");
const emailController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, subject, message } = req.body;

    // Set up emailjs parameters
    const emailData = {
      service_id: "your_service_id",
      template_id: "your_template_id",
      user_id: "your_user_id",
      template_params: {
        to_name: "Recipient Name",
        from_name: name,
        from_email: email,
        subject: subject,
        message: message,
      },
    };

    // Send email using emailjs
    const response = await emailjs.send(
      emailData.service_id,
      emailData.template_id,
      emailData.template_params,
      emailData.user_id
    );

    console.log("Email sent successfully");
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Email sent successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to send email:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to send email" });
  }
};
```

router:

```
router.post("/send", emailController);
```

I am using emailjs for the very first time. So I need help to resolve this error